# How to list all references to a symbol in all translation units in the current project in lsp-mode with clangd server?

Tags: lsp-mode

### Question

My would like to open up a `.C` file, position point (cursor) onto a symbol, type <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd>, and show **all** references to that symbol under point, in **all** translation units in the project.  But it does not do that, but only shows references in that buffer, or in other C++ files buffers (in the same [projectile](https://projectile.mx/) project) I have already opened in Emacs, files that are configured into the `compile_commands.json` file that is fed to clangd LSP server that is configured into the `lsp-mode` package in Emacs.  This is Emacs version 27.2 running on a RHEL8 host.

I have ascertained (see **Details** section below) that, even after clangd has finished indexing all translation units, the <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> still does not show all of the references to  symbol under point in all translation units.

So, is there something I can change or configure that forces `lsp-mode` (or clangd itself) to report **all** references to the symbol under point in **all** translation units, even if those source files have not yet been opened up in Emacs?

### Details

I have [lsp clangd](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-clangd/) server configured properly using the tips at [Morten's Dev](https://www.mortens.dev/blog/emacs-and-the-language-server-protocol/#:%7E:text=setq%20lsp%2Dclients%2Dclangd%2Dargs) blog. <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> is bound by default by `lsp-mode` to `xref-find-references` because `lsp-enable-xref` is currently set to `t`.  The `compile_commands.json` file that I have properly configured: It has one compile line per translation unit, for a total of ~11,000 files.

```el
(use-package lsp-clangd
  :config
  ;; From https://www.mortens.dev/blog/emacs-and-the-language-server-protocol/#:~:text=setq%20lsp%2Dclients%2Dclangd%2Dargs
  ;;
  ;;   It tells clangd that it can use 4 concurrent jobs and to make a complete
  ;;   background index on disk. Without -background-index, it will only keep an
  ;;   in-memory index of the files that are active in Emacs buffers, but to be
  ;;   able to find references and symbols in any project file the background
  ;;   index is recommended. The background index, named “.clangd” by default,
  ;;   is placed at the root of the project.
  ;;
  (setq lsp-clients-clangd-args (append lsp-clients-clangd-args '(
                                                                  "-j=4"
                                                                  "-background-index"
                                                                  "-log=error" ;; Only show errors but comment this out if/when we desire to see what it is doing in detail
                                                                  ))))
```

When I comment out the `"-log=error"` line above, I do see it re-reading index files, and indexing files also dynamically. For instance, looking at the resulting `.cache/clangd/index` that clangd produces, sorted by modification timestamp, repeatedly, shows that those idx files are being generated:

```
/path/to/my/source/tree/.cache/clangd/index:
total used in directory 141060 available 789.5 GiB
drwxrwx--- 2 drunkard saloon 2236416 Mar 19 19:27 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drunkard saloon     352 Mar 19 19:27 some_file_1.cxx.DA6F8114A502DB9B.idx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drunkard saloon     384 Mar 19 19:27 some_file_2.C.898F85D2653F3AC4.idx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drunkard saloon     864 Mar 19 19:27 some_file_3.C.3D9D3F9DA5EE5E8D.idx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 drunkard saloon     738 Mar 19 19:27 some_file_4.C.7E32A213B7D4F758.idx
```

But, even when those files stop being updated (which I conclude that indexing has finished), <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> still does not reveal all references for the symbol that I *know* are there (via other slow means such as `grep -R ...` etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the answer to the question [Why does clangd not return all references for a symbol?](https://clangd.llvm.org/faq):

> If you are sure all files are indexed and can be accessed: clangd limits the number of returned results to prevent UI freezes by default. If you have more than a 1000 symbols and you would like to get through all of them, please pass `--limit-references=0` to clangd invocation.

Comment: Thanks. So, given that it seems as if clangd does support returning all of the references or at least 1,000 of them by default. Thus, this leads me to conclude that lsp-mode is not respecting or processing all of those references properly, limiting the amount of returned references only to those translation units corresponding to opened buffers in Emacs.  Or, lsp-mode is not designed to return all of those references. Or, this is just user-error on my part, and I'm not configuring the mode properly in the first place.

Comment: I don't know your lsp configuration - Mortens-dev seems to be a little outdated, e.g. ```company-lsp``` is now part of lsp, not needed as separate package, ```helm-xref``` need to be added to the installation. Better see this page:
https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide. Although recommended , ```helm-lsp``` seems to have a similar issue - finding symbols fail (emacs 27), see this: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/helm-lsp/issues/19. In such cases, a good idea is to try another tool (e.g. vscode) - at least you can find out if the problem is clangd or emacs lsp.

Comment: Hmmm "try another tool (e.g., vscode)" : That is indeed an intriguing idea! Thank you. Yes, the Mortens-dev is a bit outdated for sure, and in fact, I'm using Ivy integration with lsp--mode and not Helm.